# Reference master controller from detail controller

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

In the top of my detailcontroller I have a button to show a list of selected items from various options on the detail controller.
I want to initialize and keep the model, the popover and the list objects in the mastercontroller. How can I get a reference to my mastercontroller to reuse these objects?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing data between views is easiest using a model tied to the component. If you make sure that everything that's selected in the master model is contained in that model, you will be able to use the data from the model in the detail view again.

Pulling data directly from another controller would go against the MVC paradigm and is not recommended (although not impossible, using e.g. the sap.ui.getCore().byId() method). I would not go there unless you have a clear view of the consequences.